# How to Delay / Sleep Canvas using DrawCircle inside of a Cycle [Android]

Tags: java, android, canvas, delay, sleep

really need your help.

Im tryng to do a delay in Canvas.

I have a path inside of a list to paint and i'm tryng to paint point by point inside of that list.

I'm using handler(and i tryied Timer also) but it is an inner class so i cant access the index(int i) that is used on for.

Where is what i'm tryng to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          c.drawCircle(path.get(i).getxPosition(), path.get(i).getyPosition(), 3, painter); 
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);

}
```

Thanks,
Stuart

Comment: make i your class value

Comment: instead of postDelayed, use sleep(500) //500 is millisecond

Comment: As i read on another posts here its not appropriated call a sleep in a UI activity :/

Comment: Guys?? any help? thaaaanks